# matching none or more Lua pattern

Tags: regex, lua, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am wondering if it was possible to make a pattern that could work like this:

With `[icon=star w=32 h=32 spin=90]`, it would return a table with:

```
icon: star  
w: 32  
h: 32  
spin: 90
```

I've tried doing `[icon=(.-) ((.-)=(.-))]` but it breaks.

Comment: The input has "spin=90" but you say you want to get "spin:32" as output. Is that an intentional translation or a typo?

Comment: You can't use regex to format results differently... but you can use regex to pull out the pertinent information in groups and then print those results however you need them

Comment: Yeah, it was very late when I wrote this so I may have made a few typos. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Lua doesn't have regex in the literal sense. It uses patterns.

So, for your case, I'd much rather use gsub(or gmatch):

```
local str = "[icon=star w=32 h=32 spin=90]"
local tR = {}
str:gsub( "(%w+)%=(%w+)", function( x, y ) tR[x] = y end )
```

And your `tR` will have the exact result you wanted.

---

More tutorials on gmatch and gsub are:

- http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial
- http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch

Comment: You can mark the reply as accepted so that the question will no be listed as unanswered. @user2150130

Answer (score 1):

Using the following expression: `(\w+(?=\=))=((?<=\=)\w+)` group 1 of each match would be the left hand side and group 2 of each match would be the right hand side.

Example: http://regexr.com?3478b

Comment: This is not valid regex syntax in lua

Comment: @m.buettner - POSIX foils me again.  Sorry I didn't do my due diligence on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\w+)=(\w+)
```

Each match will have two groups:

- Group 1 will be the "name"
- Group 2 will be the "value"

Comment: This is not valid regex syntax in lua

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in ("[icon=star w=32 h=32 spin=90]"):gmatch("(%w+)=(%w+)")
  do print(k..":",v) end

icon:   star
w:  32
h:  32
spin:   90
```